# Difference between Taylor Series and Formal Taylor Series

Tags: soft-question, taylor-expansion

I´ve read a bit about the difference, but i´m not sure if i´m getting it right. I understood that when you use the formal series, you can evaluate the series in some $X$ that is not necesarrly a number. The book used and example with $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$. Acording to the textbook, despite the fact that $f(x)$ is not continious on $x=0$, you could do the formal series exapansion of $f(X)$ where $ X = -1/x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term *formal Taylor series* is used when you want to insist that you do not address convergence questions. The [Taylor series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a function at a point is a [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) defined for any infinitely differentiable function. However, a function may not be equal to the infinite sum defined by its Taylor series, even if its Taylor series converges at every point.